# Recursively search for text between two strings

Tags: grep

I'm trying to recursively search for the text between two strings in a lot of different files.
Both of these (below) have worked while searching in one folder that has the hits.txt file but I would like to do this from a higher level directory so I don't have run either of these in every folder separately.

```
awk '/aaa/,/bbb/' hits.txt  >> As.doc
sed -n '/aaa/,/bbb/p' hits.txt > As.doc
```

I've tried various grep commands to do a recursive search like the one below, but it just creates an empty doc.

```
grep -r --include='*.txt' '/aaa/,/bbb/' > As.doc
```

I'm not sure what would work best, or if I should use find with one of the above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `grep` utility has no notion of a range of lines, like both `sed` and `awk` has, so the expression `/aaa/,/bbb/` would not do what you expect (it would just match the literal text, including the slashes and comma, which is, presumably, why you get an empty result).

Assuming that the `sed` and the `awk` command you show work and that the only thing you need help with is to apply these to files whose names end in `.txt`, recursively from the current directory.

```bsh
find . -type f -name '*.txt' -exec awk '/aaa/,/bbb/' {} + >As.doc
```

or

```bsh
find . -type f -name '*.txt' -exec sed -n '/aaa/,/bbb/p' {} + >As.doc
```

These commands would find all regular files in or below the current directory and call the `awk` or `sed` utility with batches of these.  The output from `find` (which would be the output from `awk` or `sed`) is redirected into the file called `As.doc` in the current directory (this file would be truncated (emptied) or created if it doesn't already exist).